# In Debian, C++, find a printer's node automatically

Tags: c++, printing, debian

I have this line in my code:

```
#define DEFAULT_PRINTER "/dev/usb/lp0"
```

It's node changes after pc reboots though (ex. lp3, lp2).  How can I set this automatically?  The code won't work with the wrong path.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Try `stat()` for each `/dev/usb/lp*` in the loop (should be enough if You have single printer);
- You can try modifying `udev` rules to assign fixed `lp` device numeber to Your printer;

UPDATE ( for `stat()` ):

```
char DEFAULT_PRINTER[] = "/dev/usb/lpX";
struct stat buf;
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
   DEFAULT_PRINTER[11] = '0' + i;
   if( ! stat( DEFAULT_PRINTER, &buf ) ) break;
}
```

NOTE: this is not "universal" code, it won't work for different length names (for example `/dev/usb/lp10`) without adjustments. It is just to show an idea.

Comment: How would I do that? struct stat buf; int stat ("/dev/usb/lp", &buf);

Comment: @xinthose, I've added C/C++ code fragment to use `stat()`.

Comment: It works!  thank you.  I realize now that the 11th character of buf.st_dev is its node number

Comment: No. You can simply ignore `buf` (it is not used - only return value of `stat` is). DEFAULT_PRINTER now is char array, not macro, as in Your original code. 11'th array element is changed in the loop (from '0' to '9'). Code won't work as-is for lp10 - You'll need to adjust the way printer names are created, but idea holds.

Comment: I only have one printer, so this will work well for me.